# How to pass object from data attributes to methods in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is the complete example first: https://jsfiddle.net/3bzzpajh/

What I am trying to achieve is, to pass the whole `person` object to my method `showSelectedDat`, for some reason attaching the `person` object to a data attribute like: `:data-person="person"` changes the object to something like `[object Object]` which becomes useless inside my method:

```
<div id="app">
  <select name="" id="" @change="showSelectedData($event)" >
    <option :value="person.name" :data-name="person.name"  v-for="person in people[0]"> {{ person.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As shown in the above code, I am currently "passing person" name like `:data-name="person.name"` but this becomes cumbersome when person has many properties.

This is where my vuejs application:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {

      people: [{
        '1': {
          'code': 1010,
          'name': 'sam',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'RED',
          'currencyCode': 'CHF'
        },
        '2': {
          'code': 1210,
          'name': 'jane',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'WHiTE',
          'currencyCode': 'NA'
        },
        '3': {
          'code': 7777,
          'name': 'luis',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'BLUE',
          'currencyCode': 'DE'
        },
        '4': {
          'code': 443,
          'name': 'dave',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'GREEN',
          'currencyCode': 'FR'
        }
      }]

    }
  },
  methods: {
    showSelectedData: function (event) {
      console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.name)
    }
  }
})
```

So, to recape, how do I get `person` inside `showSelectedData` when a dropdown is selected?

Comment: Why not use `v-model` instead of `change`?

Comment: What do you mean? I am a beginner, but I don't think I can use `v-model` at least not with onchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is typically done in Vue by binding a data element to the select using `v-model`.

Define a data element called `selectedPerson`.

```
data:{
  selectedPerson: null,
  ...
}
```

Reference that using `v-model`.

```
<select v-model="selectedPerson">
```

Use the person as the value in the options.

```
<option :value="person" v-for="person in people[0]"> {{ person.name }}</option>
```

Now, whenever a person is selected, `selectedPerson` will be the entire person. You don't need to use the `change` event at all, you don't need to bind it to data, and you don't need to look for it by index. When you need the selected person, just reference the data value.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the selected object key with v-model and get the person object later with the saved key. Of course you could use any other identification, for example you could save the object ID if it actually has one, and later on just find the object by that ID.

```
<div id="app">
  <select name="" id="" @change="showSelectedData($event)" v-model="current_person_key">
    <option :value="index" :data-name="person.name"  v-for="(person, index) in people[0]"> {{ person.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      current_person_key: -1,
      people: [{
        '1': {
          'code': 1010,
          'name': 'sam',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'RED',
          'currencyCode': 'CHF'
        },
        '2': {
          'code': 1210,
          'name': 'jane',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'WHiTE',
          'currencyCode': 'NA'
        },
        '3': {
          'code': 7777,
          'name': 'luis',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'BLUE',
          'currencyCode': 'DE'
        },
        '4': {
          'code': 443,
          'name': 'dave',
          'status': 'ACTIVE',
          'class': 'GREEN',
          'currencyCode': 'FR'
        }
      }]

    }
  },
  methods: {
    showSelectedData: function (event) {
        var person = this.people[0][this.current_person_key];
        console.log(person)
    }
  }
})
```